# CLI Menu library

Tags: python, object-oriented

I started writing a small CLI menu library in python. I'm uncertain of the structure and scalability  of the current code. For example the `Menu.choice` method would grow very large if were to add more options for navigation input. Could this be better done with a class to handle the input?

```
import sys
import os


class Menu(object):
    def __init__(self, *items, **kwargs):
        self.items = []
        self.title = kwargs.get('title', '')
        self.header = kwargs.get('header', '')
        for item in items:
            self.add(item)

    def add(self, *items):
        for item in items:
            self.items.append(item)
            if hasattr(item, 'subMenu'):
                self.addParentToChild(item.subMenu)

    def show(self):
        clear()
        if len(self.header):
            self.showHeader()
        if len(self.title):
            self.showTitle()
        for i, item in enumerate(self.items):
            print('[{}] {}'.format(i + 1, item.title))
        self.choice()

    def choice(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                choice = input('> ')
                if choice is 'q':
                    clear()
                    sys.exit()
                if choice is 'b':
                    if hasattr(self, 'parent'):
                        self.parent.show()
                    else:
                        self.show()
                        continue
                if not choice.isdigit():
                    raise ValueError
                item = self.items[int(choice) - 1]
                if hasattr(item, 'callback'):
                    item.callback()
                if hasattr(item, 'subMenu'):
                    item.subMenu.show()
                if not hasattr(item, 'subMenu') and not hasattr(item, 'callback'):
                    print('{} is an empty menu...'.format(item.title))
            except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
                self.show()
                continue

    def addParentToChild(self, child):
        child.parent = self

    def showTitle(self):
        print(self.title)

    def showHeader(self):
        print(self.header)


class MenuItem(object):
    def __init__(self, title, subMenu=None, callback=None, tag=''):
        self.title = title
        if subMenu is not None:
            self.subMenu = subMenu
            if len(self.title):
                subMenu.title = self.title
        if callback is not None:
            self.callback = callback
        if tag:
            self.tag = tag


def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')
```

Small example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    item1 = MenuItem('empty test 1')
    item2 = MenuItem('empty test 2')
    subMenu1 = Menu(item1, item2)
    item3 = MenuItem('sub menu', subMenu=subMenu1)
    testMenu = Menu(item1, item2, item3, title='Main Menu')
    testMenu.show()
```

Do you have any advice or suggestions about the current structure or anything else that may cause issues later on?

Answer (score 1):

- **Docstrings**: You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every method/class/module you write. This will help any documentation identify what your code is supposed to do.
- **Naming**: Python variables and parameters should be in `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.
- **`len` as condition**: You shouldn't use `if len(self.title):`, instead you should check if it doesn't exist, `if not self.title`, as it is more compliant with PEP-8. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476778/8968906) provides more insight.
- **String formatting**: This one is a personal preference. I like to use `f""` to format my strings because it allows me to directly include variables into the string, without having to chain a `.format()` onto the end. Again, this is purely personal, but see how you like it.
- **Imports**: Another personal preference, I like to organize my imports alphabetically so it's more organized. This is all up to you if you want to keep with this practice, but do make sure to follow [PEP-8 Import Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) to make sure you're following standard and accepted practies.
- **Unnecessary methods**: `show_title` and `show_header` is basically extra and unneeded code. You're essentially redefining the `print` method. Just print the title/header whenever you need to, instead of calling these methods.

***Updated Code***

```
import os
import sys

class Menu:
    """ Menu class for displaying and adding to menu """
    def __init__(self, *items, **kwargs):
        self.items = []
        self.title = kwargs.get('title', '')
        self.header = kwargs.get('header', '')
        for item in items:
            self.add(item)

    def add(self, *items):
        """ Adds each element in `list` to items """
        for item in items:
            self.items.append(item)
            if hasattr(item, 'sub_menu'):
                self.add_parent_to_child(item.sub_menu)

    def show(self):
        """ Displays the items and calls method to collect user input """
        clear()
        if self.header:
            print(self.header)
        if self.title:
            print(self.title)
        for i, item in enumerate(self.items):
            print(f"[{i + 1}] {item.title}")
        self.choice()

    def choice(self):
        """ Collects user input """
        while 1:
            try:
                choice = input('> ')
                if choice == 'q':
                    clear()
                    sys.exit()
                if choice == 'b':
                    if hasattr(self, 'parent'):
                        self.show()
                    else:
                        self.show()
                        continue
                if not choice.isdigit():
                    raise ValueError
                item = self.items[int(choice) - 1]
                if hasattr(item, 'callback'):
                    item.callback()
                if hasattr(item, 'sub_menu'):
                    item.sub_menu.show()
                if not hasattr(item, 'sub_menu') and not hasattr(item, 'callback'):
                    print(f"{item.title} is an empty menu...")
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                self.show()
                continue

    def add_parent_to_child(self, child):
        """ Adds the passed `child` to the parent of the object """
        child.parent = self


class MenuItem:
    """ Specific class for items in the menu """

    def __init__(self, title, sub_menu=None, callback=None, tag=''):
        self.title = title
        if sub_menu is not None:
            self.sub_menu = sub_menu
            if self.title:
                sub_menu.title = self.title
        if callback is not None:
            self.callback = callback
        if tag:
            self.tag = tag

def clear():
    """ Clears the console screen """
    os.system('cls') if os.name == 'nt' else os.system('clear')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ITEM_1 = MenuItem('empty test 1')
    ITEM_2 = MenuItem('empty test 2')
    SUBMENU_1 = Menu(ITEM_1, ITEM_2)
    ITEM_3 = MenuItem('sub menu', sub_menu=SUBMENU_1)
    TEST_MENU = Menu(ITEM_1, ITEM_2, ITEM_3, title='Main Menu')
    TEST_MENU.show()
```

Comment: A couple of points: 1. You don't need `()` in class definition, `class Menu` will do just fine. 2. I don't think this: `if not choice.isdigit(): raise ValueError` has any effect at all. But good suggestions

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex Yeah I should probably update this answer :P